# OnClick to move from more than two activities ?

Tags: android, onclick

I'm a beginner in android developing , I tried to make many activities ( screens ) , when clicking the first button it takes me to the second screen , but when I click on the button of the second screen to move to the third screen the app won't work !

This is my XML code :

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fal"
        android:onClick="kahwah" />
```

and this is how it is in java :

```
    public void kahwah(View V)
{
    Intent i2 = new Intent (this,Third.class);
    startActivity(i2);
}
```

Comment: Does not work!. Does the app crash?

Comment: paste your crash log here

Comment: @AbdullahADhaim post the stacktrace

Comment: Have you added your activity in manifest file?

Comment: I think you forgot to mention Third activity in manifest file

Comment: no i did not ! @shylendra

Comment: @pratik this comes to me in console

Comment: @AbdullahADhaim So you need to add it in manifest file see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mention your activities in Android manifest file of application tag like:

```
<activity android:name="com.your_package_name.YourActivity" />
```

in the application tag.

Comment: He cant go to the second screen if he dont know how to add the activities to manifest, but he saying he is at 2nd.

Comment: I'm very Thankful to you my friend :)

Comment: @AbdullahADhaim If it is helped you accept my answer.

Comment: @shylendra, he replied for your comment that he did not forget.

Comment: @AbdullahADhaim Post log what you are getting in console?